# Making line chart respect time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a line chart with dates as axis X, and there's a gap in the data (e.g. there's data until the 8th, then no data, then data from the 20th). Excel displays all this on the same scope, ergo the gap between the 8th and the 20th is the same as the gap between the 7th and the 8th:
[image]
What I would like is for Excel to respect the gap, so if there's no data for multiple days, it should display those dates but with no data. In Python with PyPlot this does happen:
[image]
What should I do to achieve the same in Excel? I'm on Excel 2016 on a Mac.

Comment: I just did A1:A31 1-31/1/2019, B1:B31 with 1.1, 0.9, 1.1, 0.9 etc... then deleted data for 11-14/1, and the chart shows as expected. Are you using Line or Stacked Line? Stacked line will interpolate.

Comment: try right-clicking on the axis and select "Format Axis", make sure the Axis type is set to "Data axis" (note that this will only work if the dates in your table are actual dates and not strings)

Comment: You can't make a line chart respect time.  Line charts treat the dates as categories; they're just labels.  It stacks the data one after the other in sequence.  If you want it to reflect time, the X axis needs to be treated as a continuous variable, where the dates are numbers on a chronological scale (they are actually stored internally as numbers; just make sure the cells contain Excel dates rather than text representations of dates; and you will probably need to format the X axis with a date format so it looks like dates).  Use a scatter chart (XY chart), which does that.